# How do I instruct Eclipse that JDK 1.6 is a Java 1.6 compatible JRE?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, java-6

I am running Eclipse Juno (so that I can still run EclEmma) and have jdk 1.6.0_45 installed. I used to have jre 1.6 installed, but then whenever I would re-import from my maven poms I'd lose all debug information in the libraries, so I've switched.

Every so often, and I haven't yet figured out what triggers it, all of my projects (and there are over 100, so it's a pain to fix them all) decide that they need a 1.6 jre and that none is available. *I can see jdk1.6.0_45 in the Installed JREs list, but it's not available in the Execution Environment pane under JavaSE-1.6*. The only solution I've found so far is to edit all the .project files so that they refer to JaveaSE-1.6/JRE_CONTAINER again and restart Eclipse. This takes nearly an hour (because it needs to rebuild everything twice) which is a large loss of time in a day.

So the question I have is, is there any way to force Eclipse to see that the JDK *that it is running in* is a valid JavaSE-1.6 environment?

Answer (score 0):

Déclare your JRE in Window > Preferences > Java > Installed JREs (seems already done)

In Installed JREs > Execution Environments > JavaSE-1.6, check the JRE you want (jdk1.6.0_45)

Now all your projects need to have the JRE System Library using an execution environment JavaSE-1.6 (You should see your jre name next  to it).

Answer (score 0):

You need to go Windows->Preferences->Java->Installed JREs->Execution Environments and here choose JavaSE-1.6 in the left column and mark your jdk1.6.0_45 as compatible.